Long image rendering time when using Grafana image renderer plugin
The following configuration is available:
Grafana and Grafana Image Renderer are installed as separate pods in the same k8s namespace, Grafana has access via Service to the Grafana image renderer pod, which in turn runs a server on localhost:8080
Link to plugin description: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-image-renderer/?tab=overview
The problem is that when rendering a 3000X15000 page, it takes an infinite amount of time, a 3000X5000 size is rendered acceptably.
I can't figure out what exactly the problem is.
I tried to track resource consumption when executing a request by cores, processor load, and RAM usage by processes inside the container, but I did not notice a lack of resources. I tried to interact with the plugin through environment variables, setting the maximum number of parallel processes, but this also did not help.
Perhaps there are settings for this plugin that it is advisable to use when running the plugin in a Docker container for more efficient rendering?
Could there be a problem with the nodejs web server? I had no experience with it before.
